# Error al enviar una Lista de objetos hacia la Vista en Java Spring tool 4

Tags: java, spring

spring tool me tira error al enviar una Lista de objetos.
Funciona si envío un solo objeto, si envío una lista me tira este error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Tue Nov 03 18:24:30 ART 2020
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
> Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "post.title" (template: "index" - line 47, col 21)

Muchas gracias!!

```
package com.floxy.core.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.floxy.core.model.Post;
import com.floxy.core.model.Prueba;



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class ControllerBasic {      
    
    public List<Prueba> getPrueba() {
        Prueba prue1 = new Prueba(1,"descripcion", "img", "titulo");    
        Prueba prue2 = new Prueba(2,"descripcion2", "img2", "titulo2"); 
        
        List<Prueba> listaPruebas = new ArrayList<>();
        listaPruebas.add(prue1);
        listaPruebas.add(prue2);
            
        
        return listaPruebas;
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping(path = {"/post", "/"})
    public String saludar(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("post", this.getPrueba());
        return "index";     
    }
    
}


        <!-- open card --> 
          <div th:each="post : ${posts}" class="col-3"/>             
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="../static/img/img-flower.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 th:text="${post.title}" class="card-title">adfasdf</h5>
                <p th:text="${post.description}" class="card-text"></p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary"></a>
              </div>
            </div>                          
          </div>
          <!-- close card -->
```

Comment: Agrega la clase Prueba, puede que el problema se encuentre allí.

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes está en:

```
model.addAttribute("post", this.getPrueba());
```

Tal y como tienes en la vista `post` debería ser en plural:

```
model.addAttribute("posts", this.getPrueba());
```

Comment: Hola! lo cambié, pero me sigue tirando el mismo error `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "post.title" (template: "index" - line 47, col 21)`

Comment: ¿Cómo es la clase `Prueba`?