# There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Hola asi que estoy metiendome a practicar con java y spring boot para realizarla una aplicacion web. El problema parece estar relacionado a las rutas Llevo horas tratando de resolver esto y no logro resolverlo. Simplemente cuando ingreso a cuaquier ruta obtengo este error:

> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping
> for /error, so you are seeing this as a
> fallback. There was an unexpected error
> (type=Not Found, status=404). No message.
> available

Todo pese a que en mi controller se supone ya defini mis rutas. Entonces tengo estos archivos:

### UsersController

```
package controllers;


import models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import services.UserService;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UsersController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    public UsersController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

  @GetMapping
    public String getAllUsers() {
    // Maneja las solicitudes GET para obtener todos los usuarios
    return "Mensaje de respuesta para la ruta /users";
}

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        // Maneja las solicitudes GET para obtener un usuario por su ID
        return userService.getUserById(userId);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        // Maneja las solicitudes POST para guardar un nuevo usuario
        return userService.saveUser(user);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{userId}")
    public void deleteUser(@PathVariable Long userId) {
        // Maneja las solicitudes DELETE para eliminar un usuario por su ID
        userService.deleteUser(userId);
    }
}
```

### un UserService

```
package services;

import models.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import repositories.UserRepository;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    public List<User> getAllUsers() {
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    public User getUserById(Long userId) {
        return userRepository.findById(userId).orElse(null);
    }

    public ResponseEntity<Object> saveUser(User user) {
        try {
            User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
            // Éxito: Devuelve un mensaje de éxito en formato JSON
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("{\"message\": \"Usuario registrado correctamente\"}");
        } catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
            // Error: La inserción falló debido a una violación de integridad
            // Devuelve un mensaje de error en formato JSON
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("{\"message\": \"Error al intentar guardar el usuario\"}");
        }
    }

    public void deleteUser(Long userId) {
        userRepository.deleteById(userId);
    }
}
```

### el metodo main

```
package com.example.streaming_nuevo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers")


public class StreamingNuevoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StreamingNuevoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

### Y el archivo pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>streaming_nuevo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>streaming_nuevo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- configuracion db -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- validaciones -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <builder>paketobuildpacks/builder-jammy-base:latest</builder>
                    </image>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Por lo que entiendo eh definido correctamente las rutas, pero haga lo que haga lo único que obtengo es esta pagina de error

`Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.`
No se realmente que me falta intente de todo pero no logro entender que esta mal o que me falta. Estoy usando java version 17 junto con spring boot 3.15.

Actualizacion: no se si sea relevante pero tambien adjunto la organizacion de archivos

[image: estructura de archivos]

Comment: Te recomiendo poner la traza de error completa, normalmente después de ese mensaje viene la razón de error, por ejemplo como en este otro post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/403664/error-al-enviar-una-lista-de-objetos-hacia-la-vista-en-java-spring-tool-4

Comment: Gracias por responder sencillamente son errores 404

Comment: yo el problema que le veo es que le estás diciendo que solo cargue los componentes que están en `com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers` y en tu clase controlador declaras que está en otro paquete llamado `controllers`

Comment: Ojalá fuera eso probé eso probé así `@ComponentScan(basePackages ="controllers")` y sigo con ese mismo error

Comment: con probé así te refieres a que pasaste lo de tu paquete controller al paquete `com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers` así como todos los demás paquetes dentro de `com.example.streaming_nuevo`?

Comment: En realidad probé así

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers")`
Y asi
`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "controllers")` y no consigue ninguna solucion

Comment: si todo tu código o parte de él está en paquetes arriba del paquete donde declaras `@ComponentScan` no se cargará en el spring IoC container y por lo tanto no estará disponible en el contexto

Comment: Bueno en realidad me confunde un poco lo de la organización pero como se ve en la captura en este caso no sabría como solucionar eso

Comment: solo reorganízalo como te indiqué aunque te confunda y nos actualizas cuando lo hayas hecho si con eso se soluciona

Comment: No me quedo claro disculpa la molestia si podrías en la respuesta más o menos explicar esa parte. Como se supone debería organizar esto y ver si puedo encontrar solución a este problema

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149757/discussion-between-ruslan-lopez-and-fer-daniela).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como te indica Ruslan en los comentarios, el problema puede ser la extraña distribución de tus clases en los diferentes paquetes.

La idea es que todas tus clases "cuelguen" de un paquete común y que la clase que arranque la aplicación esté en la raíz de ese paquete. Lo normal es que no se especifique ningún paquete concreto en la etiqueta @ComponentScan, ya que

> Using @ComponentScan in a Spring Application. With Spring, we use the
> @ComponentScan annotation along with the @Configuration annotation to
> specify the packages that we want to be scanned. @ComponentScan
> without arguments tells Spring to scan the current package and all of
> its sub-packages. [Fuente](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning#:%7E:text=Using%20%40ComponentScan%20in%20a%20Spring,all%20of%20its%20sub%2Dpackages.)

es decir, si pones únicamente `@ComponentScan` sin argumentos, Spring te escaneará el paquete actual y todos sus subpaquetes.

Si pones tu clase `StreamingNuevoApplication` en el paquete `com.example.streaming`, tus otras clases deberían estar en `com.example.streaming.services`, `com.example.streaming.controllers`, ...

Nota: Por convención no se suele emplear el _ en los nombres de paquetes.

[Pero en las últimas versiones de SpringBoot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35006877/2553194) la etiqueta `@SpringBootApplication` ya engloba estas tres con sus valores por defecto:  `@Configuration, @EnableAutoConfiguration, @ComponentScan`
Además, también en las últimas versiones, por defecto `@ComponentScan`, sin nada más, sirve para instanciar todos los beans que encuentre definidos en el classpath de tu proyecto. Resumiendo, que puedes quitar esa etiqueta.

Por otro lado, no se trata de que hayas definido o no las rutas. Puede que Spring te esté instanciando esos controladores, servicios y repositorios y aun así te esté saliendo ese error 404. Eso no quiere decir necesariamente que la ruta no exista. Ese error puede estar enmascarándote otro problema distinto. Para hallar la causa raíz lo mejor es ver qué está saliendo en el fichero de log del servidor, que en cualquier IDE como IntelliJ te estará saliendo en alguna de tus pestañas. En él seguramente encontrarás un volcado de pila indicándote la línea de código exacta que está provocando ese error.

Una vez hayas encontrado ese volcado de pila o stacktrace, ya sea en tu IDE o en la ruta donde tengas instalado el servidor, si no eres capaz de encontrar la solución, puedes crear una nueva pregunta incluyendo dicho volcado más la estructura de los elementos afectados de tu proyecto.

Answer (score 2):

Spring no está encontrando (y por tanto no está instanciando) las clases de tus componentes:

1. La clase "main" está en el paquete `com.example.streaming_nuevo`.
2. Las anotaciones

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers")
```

Le dicen a Spring que busque componentes en el paquete `com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers` y sus hijos.

3. Tus componentes están repartidos en paquetes que no están donde has indicado.

Te recomiendo reestructurar la jerarquía a algo como

```
com.example.streaming
  |   StreamingNuevoApplication
  | - controller
  | |   UsersController
  | - service
  | |   UserService
  | - respository
    |   UserRepository
```

y eliminar las anotaciones no necesarias (deja sólo `@SpringBootApplication`).

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a sus comentarios logre entender mejor el problema. Al final lo que hice fue es organizar las carpetas y pude solventar este problema la estructura quedo en efecto como recomendaba @Pablo Lozano

```
com.example.streaming
  |   StreamingNuevoApplication
  | - controller
  | |   UsersController
  | - service
  | |   UserService
  | - respository
    |   UserRepository
```

por lo que los repositorios que antes tenia solo como controlles, models, services, y repositories quedaron como
`com.example.streaming_nuevo.controllers`, `com.example.streaming_nuevo.models`, `com.example.streaming_nuevo.services`, `com.example.streaming_nuevo.repositories`
Si alguien a futuro enfrenta un problema similar mas o menos ya sabe donde podria estar el problema.